# FileMerge error message when used with Git difftool

Tags: filemerge

I use FileMerge as the `difftool` tool for Git. Recently, I started receiving a weird error message:

```
Unable to load platform at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/
   Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
```

FileMerge still performs the diff just fine (although it takes a bit longer to load). Any idea what's causing this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Same here for SVN. Are you using a wrapper for opendiff (like fmdiff)?

Comment: @surlac - No, just plain vanilla opendiff.

Comment: Also the same here with hg.

Comment: FWIW, all these went away after updating to the latest version of XCode.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem while using FileMerge as a diff tool for svnX. The following command solved my problem:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on user3761183's answer, after a bit of [googling](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050430105126392) I ran:

```
sudo plutil -convert xml1 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/*.platform/Info.plist
```

That got rid of all the `Unable to load platform at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform` errors. I'm still getting errors about:

> Couldn't load '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/Core Build System.xcspec'. Reason: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character b at line 1" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character b at line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected ';' or '=' after key at line 1" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected ';' or '=' after key at line 1}}.

But I was getting them originally too, so if you aren't then the above command should solve your problems.

EDIT: removed comment about `Install addtional required components` that did nothing. Next guess is reinstalling XCode as Jonathan F suggests.

FWIW I tried `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` already and that did nothing too.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with Mercurial, too: [Unable to load platform at path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617644/unable-to-load-platform-at-path)

If you don't develop for iOS, you can just delete that folder.  If you do, you'll have to re-install XCode. (Unless you can figure out how to re-install just that platform).

I'm thinking you're better off just re-installing XCode, as there are some other SO questions dealing with platform related problems (not this specifically, but similar in nature) that all seem to point to reinstalling XCode:

[XCODE fail to load platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178282/xcode-fail-to-load-platform)

and

[Xcode won't open: "Mac OS X platform is missing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706642/xcode-wont-open-mac-os-x-platform-is-missing)

....so start re-installing and go get a beer!

Answer (score 0):

for me, converting all *.platform/Info.plist from binary to xml1 fixed the problem. strange ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read ["How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I use XCode for my `$ git mergetool` and have gotten similar errors. For me, it's been related to XCode's components/simulators and documents.

Go to XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads and make sure you have the latest components and documents.

*I'm only here because I updated to XCode 7 and I'm getting similar errors because of Apple Watch documentation combined with my employer letting our dev license expire...*

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the problem highlighted by jim in his answer, related to the `"Unexpected character b at line 1"` error, I found that `Core Build System.strings` and `Native Build System.strings` files at the path specified by the error message i.e. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/` are in some sort of binary format. The parser doesn't expect this and complains about the `character b` of the word `bplist` opening the file. Maybe playing with `plutil` as in the "platform problem" which the OP was asking about can help. I simply substituted the two files with versions from a Xcode 6 dmg, where they are in ASCII format and the problem vanished